# how to handle enum constant renaming with XStream?

Tags: java, enums, xstream

I have renamed an enum constant in my source code.

From

```
public enum MyEnum { FOO, BAR }
```

To

```
public enum MyEnum { FOO, BAZ }
```

Now if I try to read back old data previously serialized with xstream, I get a `ConversionException: "No enum constant MyEnum BAR"`.

I tried aliasing:

```
xstream.aliasField("BAR", MyEnum.class, "BAZ");
```

But that did not help.

Any idea how to read this old xstream serialized file with the new code?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to alias an enum constant.

A converter can do the job in a few lines

public class MyEnumConverter implements Converter {

```
...

public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
    context.convertAnother(source, reflectionConverter);
}

public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
    String s = reader.getValue();
    if (s.equals("BAR")) {
        return MyEnum.BAZ;
    } else {
        return MyEnum.valueOf(s);
    }
}

public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
    return type == MyEnum.class;
}
```

}

Comment: Worked for me. And just used it for the step of reading old .XML since the generation had to be with the new names, so I only registered it for de-serializing.